# Run particular query if field is null

Tags: mysql, case

So I want to run different queries depending whether one field is null. Here is what i have

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN vehicle_uid IS NULL THEN (SELECT lic_num, vehicle_make, vehicle_model, zone.name
                    FROM notice
                    INNER JOIN zone on notice.zone_uid = zone.uid

                    WHERE lic_num IN (
                        SELECT lic_num 
                        FROM notice
                        GROUP BY lic_num 
                        HAVING count(*) > 1
                    ))

ELSE (SELECT lic_num, vehicle_uid, model.model, make.make, zone.name
    FROM notice
    INNER JOIN vehicle_model AS model ON notice.vehicle_uid = model.uid
    INNER JOIN vehicle_make AS make ON model.vehicle_make_uid = make.uid
    INNER JOIN zone on notice.zone_uid = zone.uid

    WHERE lic_num IN (
        SELECT lic_num 
        FROM notice
        GROUP BY lic_num 
        HAVING count(*) > 1
    ))
END
```

The error I get is `#1054 - Unknown column 'vehicle_uid' in 'field list'`  When I change the `WHEN vehicle_uid IS NULL` to `WHEN notice.vehicle_uid IS NULL` the error says: `#1109 - Unknown table 'notice' in field list`

I have also tried
`SELECT 
    CASE vehicle_uid
    WHEN IS NULL THEN ...` and following error comes up: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL THEN (SELECT lic_num, vehicle_make, vehicle_model, zone.name FROM n' at line 3`

Im just starting with more complex queries and have no idea why is this wrong.

Comment: You can't do a subquery into a select statement that returns more than one field and nor returning more than one row. The error you are seeing is because you are selecting a field `vehicle_uid` from no where, you don't have a `from` clause to the database know where it came from.

Comment: I have tried adding the `from` clause at the very end which gave me the `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) ` error

Comment: See my answer. Anything else, just ask

Comment: Hi there, if the answer helped you, consider in accepting it. By clicking on the little V link on the left side of the answer. But only if it really helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use UNION with two different SELECT statements that return same columns.

```
(SELECT lic_num, vehicle_make uid_or_make, vehicle_model, '', zone.name
    FROM notice
    INNER JOIN zone on notice.zone_uid = zone.uid
    WHERE lic_num IN (SELECT lic_num FROM notice GROUP BY lic_num  HAVING count(*) > 1) AND vehicle_uid IS NULL
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT lic_num, vehicle_uid uid_or_make, model.model vehicle_model, make.make, zone.name
    FROM notice
    INNER JOIN vehicle_model AS model ON notice.vehicle_uid = model.uid
    INNER JOIN vehicle_make AS make ON model.vehicle_make_uid = make.uid
    INNER JOIN zone on notice.zone_uid = zone.uid
    WHERE lic_num IN (SELECT lic_num FROM notice GROUP BY lic_num HAVING count(*) > 1) AND vehicle_uid IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `FROM` clause from your outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a subquery into a `select` statement that returns more than one field and nor returning more than one row. The error you are seeing is because you are selecting a field `vehicle_uid` from nowhere, you don't have a `from` clause to the database know where it came from.

Best way to solve your problem is to do a `UNION` with the specific conditions but it will only work if the two queries has the same set of columns so:

```
SELECT lic_num, 
       vehicle_make,
       '' SUBSTITUTE_FORVEHICLEUID,
       vehicle_model, 
       '' SUBSTITUTE_FOR_MAKE,
       zone.name
  FROM notice
        INNER JOIN zone ON notice.zone_uid = zone.uid
 WHERE lic_num IN (
           SELECT lic_num 
             FROM notice
            GROUP BY lic_num 
           HAVING count(*) > 1
         )
   AND vehicle_uid is null
UNION
SELECT lic_num,  
       '' SUBSTITUTE_FOR_VEHICLEMAKE, 
       vehicle_uid, 
       model.model, 
       make.make, 
       zone.name
  FROM notice
      INNER JOIN vehicle_model AS model ON notice.vehicle_uid = model.uid
      INNER JOIN vehicle_make AS make ON model.vehicle_make_uid = make.uid
      INNER JOIN zone on notice.zone_uid = zone.uid
 WHERE lic_num IN (
        SELECT lic_num 
        FROM notice
        GROUP BY lic_num 
        HAVING count(*) > 1
      )
   AND vehicle_uid IS NOT NULL
```

Even though this is the best option for your problem you will have to adjust both queries. Since I don't know your structure that is the best I can help with.